# Remove unwanted and uncomprehensible space in powershell script

Tags: powershell, formatting, powershell-2.0, whitespace

I have done a little powershell script to get infos about system drives and then write them in the console, and then export the output stream to json format. Everything works fine, I got the infos, and then write in the json format, but a white space appears in the diskName value which I have to remove to then explore my data.

This is my script :

```
$drives = Get-PSDrive -PSProvider 'FileSystem'
ForEach ($drive in $drives)
{
    if ( ($drive.Used -ne 0) -and ($drive.Free -ne $null))
    { 
        $Name = $drive.Name
        Write-Host $Name
        Write-Host '{"name":"disk", "diskName":"'$Name'"}'
    }
}
```

I would like to have this ouput :

```
C
{"name":"disk", "diskName":"C"}
D
{"name":"disk", "diskName":"D"}
P
{"name":"disk", "diskName":"P"}
```

But I am getting this :

```
C
{"name":"disk", "diskName":" C"}
D
{"name":"disk", "diskName":" D"}
P
{"name":"disk", "diskName":" P"}
```

If anyone has an explaination about this white space, It would be very usefull.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you're using PowerShell v3 or newer, there's no need to write your own JSON; use `ConvertTo-JSON`.

```
Get-PSDrive -PSProvider Filesystem |
    Where-Object {$_.Used -ne 0 -and $_.Free -ne $null} |
    Select-Object -property @{Name="Name";Expression={"disk"}},@{Name="Diskname";Expression={$_.name}} |
    ConvertTo-Json;
```

Since v2 compatibility is a requirement:

```
Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem|
    Where-Object {$_.Used -ne 0 -and $_.Free -ne $null}|
    ForEach-Object{
        Write-output "{`"name`":`"disk`",`"diskName`":`"$($_.name)`"}"
    };
```

Comment: Thanks, but :                                                                              I am using an old version of powershell and I need to stay on it.               For some application architecture reasons, I need to get an output console stream in a json format. So I really and only need to understand the origin of this whitespace and if possible, remove it.

Comment: I've added a v2-compatible version

Answer (score 1):

Or you could change this:

```
    Write-Host '{"name":"disk", "diskName":"'$Name'"}'
```

To this:

```
    Write-Host "{`"name`":`"disk`", `"diskName`":`"$Name`"}"
```

The single quotes act differently from double quotes, and change the behavior when attempting to insert a variable into the string.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
get-psdrive -psprovider FileSystem | foreach-object {
  if ( ($_.Used -ne 0) -and ($_.Free -ne $NULL) ) {
      $_.Name
      "{`"name`":`"disk`", `"diskName`":`"$($_.Name)`"}"
  }
}
```